# Redrawing NSButton when mouseDown and mouseUp

Tags: macos, cocoa, subclass, nsbutton

I subclassing `NSButton` and perform custom drawing. I imlement methods `-mouseDown` and    `-mouseUp`. When i perform short(fast) click, my code work perfect, but if i hold down left mouse button some time then release it, method `-mouseUp` didn't work.
Perhaps i don't understand how the buttons work... So I want the buttons to change appearance when mouse is down, and return to previous when it goes up. 
What i do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting this behavior is that there are two different ways to handle mouse dragging in Cocoa. Both are discussed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW18

NSButton is most likely using "The Mouse-Tracking Loop Approach", where everything (including the mouse-up event) is done within the `mouseDown:` method. So in the case you are wondering about, this is how things could look like in your `NSButton` subclass:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
  someIvar = NO;

  [super mouseDown:event];

  //sometimes, when you are here, you have already had the "mouse up"
  //because super's mouseDown did everything.

  //to find out if this is the case, one solution would be to put
  //an instance variable into your subclass (someIvar)

  if (someIvar == YES)
  {
    //you have a "mouse up"
  }
  else
  {
    //you don't have a "mouse up"
  }
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
  someIvar = YES;
}
```